# Present UITableViewController from Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, storyboard

I have built up a UITableViewController inside my storyboard and now need to present it modally programatically (I can't link the transition/segue inside my storyboard).

I have linked my custom UITableViewController class to the controller I made in the storyboard and imported where required and trying to present it like so in my code:

```
AddEventViewController *vc = [[AddEventViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

However, it picks up nothing I have done in the storyboard, purely basing what is shown by the class contents.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to use this instead:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addEventTVC" sender:self];
```

Silly me.